# How fast does Reachability on iOS works?

Tags: ios, reachability

Does it spends some time to get current status using this code:

```
    _hostReachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:HOST_NAME];
    NetworkStatus status = [_hostReachability currentReachabilityStatus];
```

Im going to use this every time user opens the article (represented by `uiwebview`) in news application, so there must not be any lags before the article is shown in `uiwebview`

Comment: Did you try it? Are you seeing any lag?

Comment: @maddy im on slow internet connection atm so...

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Are you seeing lag from the reachability call? Yes or No?

Comment: @maddy how can I tell a reachability lag from a data downloading lag? Ofcourse I se some lag before the content loaded and diplayed on screen.

Comment: Use the debugger and step over the code. Does the debugger step over the reachability call immediately? If so, there is no lag.

Comment: @maddy ok I got you. Atleast you didn't reject my idea (the idea to check reachability before sending a request)

Comment: My goal here was to help you figure this out on your own. There is no lag calling reachability. It should be called before each network access because the reachability can change at any time.